# Why would  running ALTER TABLE  on a  column cause it to go from NOT NULL to NULL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am mass updating a SQL Server database. I am changing all our `numeric(38,0)` columns to `int` *(yes, SQL Server scripts were created from Oracle scripts)*.
Using SMO and C# *(I am a sw engineer)*, I managed to generate really nice scripts like *SQL Server Management studio* would. It all works very nicely except for one particular issue:

for a a handful of tables, when I call `ALTER TABLE [myTable] ALTER COLUMN [columnA] INT` it decides to also change the column from `NOT NULL to NULL`. That of course is a huge issue since I need to regenerate primary keys for most of those tables on those particular columns.

Obviously, I have plenty of options using SMO to find out which columns are primary keys and force them to be NOT NULL after or while I am updating the data type, but I am really curious as to what can be causing this.

Comment: You can find this out if columns are members of the primary key via T/SQL as well.  SMO isn't required.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on your setting of [SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187356.aspx) or [SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187375.aspx) (read these for other effects too from SET ANSI_DEFAULTS).

Personally, I'd have specified this constraint *explicitly* if I wanted null or non null columns rather than relying on environment settings.

```
ALTER TABLE [myTable] ALTER COLUMN [columnA] INT NOT NULL
```

You can issue this command again and if a column is already at the desired nullability the command is ignored.

However, you also said that you only need to change it where it's part of a primary key. That should have no bearing on whether a column can be nullable or not from the modelling/implementation phase

Comment: `SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON` doesn't apply here. [ANSI_NULL defaults are always on for ALTER COLUMN; if not specified, the column is nullable.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)